# How to enable debugging express.js/node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, package.json

I am working on express.js in window environment. I have successfully started my project with `npm start`. Now I need to add debug statement in `package.json` file to enable debugging.

Like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "DEBUG=fibonacci:* node ./bin/www"
}
```

After I have edited in `package.json` and `npm start` command I am facing error:

```
Error: Debug is not an internal or external command
```

Note: I am following Node.js book and in the book it executes successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers above are correct but they are just cmd session based ,if we close cmd then we need to set the debug variable again.
after some debugging i found the correct way

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set DEBUG=fibonacci:* & node ./bin/www"
}
```

we just need to put the set command in the package.json file itself,In that way you can store as many as variable you want like port also.

Answer (score 5):

Setting environment variables in npm scripts is platform specific.

On Windows:

```
"start": "set DEBUG=fibonacci:*&& mocha --reporter spec"
```

On Unix / macOS:

```
"start": "DEBUG=fibonacci:* mocha --reporter spec"
```

I recommend to use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) (`npm i -D cross-env`), which deals with those differences and works on all platforms:

```
"start": "cross-env DEBUG=fibonacci:* mocha --reporter spec"
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you must set DEBUG as a environment variable

```
set DEBUG=you_application
```

Comment: that way it works...but it temporarily ,i mean closing and starting the command prompt i need to set it again.Is there any way it can work by editing the package.json???

Comment: if you try from console: 

1. cd in your app
2. npm install
3. set DEBUG=app
4. npm start 

It should not be temporary...

Comment: But, he will have to repeat these steps, everytime when he opens up a new CMD window right?

Comment: with WebStorm, i set this variable from Edit Configurations... in windows i think it's possible in this way: 

- Use the global Search Charm to search "Environment Variables"
- Click "Edit system environment variables"
- Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
- In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include C:\Program Files\nodejs .

Comment: iam not sure how it will help after adding path C:\Program Files\nodejs,but i tried and it not works

Comment: @AtulSaini, To make this actually create the server after setting the DEBUG variable is like this: `set DEBUG=express:* && node server.js`

Answer (score 1):

### The way I do it:

```
set DEBUG=your_project:* & npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

With nodemon, on windows:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "SET \"DEBUG=express:*\"&& nodemon ./bin/www"
},
```